# Previewing Fonts in Designer in Xamarin.FORMS

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I made a Xamarin.Forms project and I referenced my own font and then added an alias in the assembly like so:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Samantha.ttf", Alias = "MyAwesomeCustomFont")]
```

Now... the thing is, this font which I have referenced is NOT being shown in the designer, instead I'm still getting the default font, even *after* referencing it:

```
<Button WidthRequest="70" Text="Click me" FontFamily="MyAwesomeCustomFont"/>
```

[image]

Now, this is frustrating because **it is working when I deploy it and it showing the font**
although I want the designer to illustrate exactly what's going on, so I do want the custom font to be shown in the designer... Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I tested a basic demo about the function and faced the same issue. The custom font works fine when building the project. But the FontFamily is not be consumed in the previewer. It seems that the previewer doesn't support the custom font. You could following the related link for a solution. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1200173/previewer-doesnt-support-custom-font.html The VS provides the **Hot Reload** function which supportsto make changes to XAML code, check the tutorial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yeah I have tried it before. But I still do preview designer but I agree I will give it a try tomorrow. (This post is still looking for answers.)

Comment: Waiting for your update and you could follow the post.

Comment: Look at my solution, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own problem. I created a custom renderer and it's showing in the preview:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace Custombutton.Droid
{
    class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetAllCaps(false);
                Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "NUNITO-BOLD.ttf");
                Control.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result in designer:

[image]